# How to write <table> markup without JSF tag libraries (h:datatable or ui:repeat) but still use JSF for controlling page flow

Tags: ajax, performance, jsf, jquery, datatable

I have various tables with the following size : 12 columns and up to 1800 rows. It takes 8 seconds to render it to the user. I currently use `h:dataTable`. I tried `ui:repeat` to get the row data from a Java List object, managed by JSF.  Although this works fine, the 8 seconds to render the table is unacceptable. I'm trying to find other ways to do this, but need to keep `JSF` as my `controller` for action buttons on the page.  In other words I want to create the 'table markup`to send to the`page myself`and then still associate actions on`h:commandButtons` to the managed bean methods. Is there a way to do this?

The only ways I can think of is to use `jquery` or `ajax` to create the table markup, although I am new to technologies other than JSF for UI development.Maybe then I would somehow pass that to the client for render.  The only problem is I don't know how to generate the markup from my list, and second how I would inject it between `h:commandButtons` that are in my `XHTML` file currently.

Does any one know how I can solve this without having to completely rip OFF JSF?  One main problem I have is that the  **business requirement that says we can't page the datatable (i.e: Next / Back buttons displaying 100 at a time for example)**.  So, possibly I was thinking I could do this by Ajax calls to the server and get 100 rows at a time after page ready, and append new rows behind the scenes to the user.  This would be a "perceived" speed of load, but I don't know how to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

8 seconds isn't bad for a whopping 1800 rows on 12 columns. 10~100 rows is done in less than a second, right?

Before continuing with this, are you absolutely positive that all those 1800 rows are supposed to be shown at once? Isn't this very user unfriendly? Wouldn't the user have to need Ctrl+F to find the information it is looking for? Isn't that annoying? Why don't you introduce filtering (a search field) and pagination exactly like as Google is doing to present the zillion of results in a sane and user friendly manner?

Anyway, you could consider using "On-Demand data" option of [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) `<p:dataTable>`, wherein the data is loaded by ajax during scrolling via `<p:dataTable liveScroll="true">`. See also the [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml). No homegrown code nor manually fiddling with jQuery necessary. PrimeFaces has done it all under the covers.

It you don't want to use PrimeFaces for some reason, then you could consider using [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) `<o:componentIdParam>` in combination with some jQuery "live scrolling" plugin. See also the last example in [its (snapshot) showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/componentIdParam) for a kickoff example (which should easily be adapted to be triggered by hitting the scroll bottom instead of by clicking).

Comment: Actually I mispoke, it is 18 columns and 1800 rows. I like your idea of doing a "live" scrolling implementation using either PrimeFaces or OmniFaces. Unfortuntely, I can not use these APIs because they are not approved by my company. I can use Rich Faces though, and we are investigating whether rich:extendedDataTable can accomplish perceived instantaneous load time when the table is actually loading in the background.